# Content in before appear with backslash

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this code for overlay ( a gradient ) in my custom css editor in wordpress:

```
.tp-bgimg.defaultimg::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#dc4225,#002f4b);
    opacity: .6;


}
```

But the problem is , in the element inspector in the browser show me:

```
content:\"\"
```

and this give me an error and the class not working.

Why show me that ?

Thank

Comment: I'm guessing you've used the wrong kind of quotes,,,that looks like "escaping" to me,

Comment: Could you try with `'` instead of `"` to see if it still escape it?

Comment: the same error using simple quotes , browser show me "invalid property value"

Comment: Well something is converting whatever quotes you are using to characters that are being escaped. My guess is that ***"my custom css editor in wordpress"*** is the issue.

Comment: i resoveld it with "open-quote" i put it in the content and its works